# npm ERESOLVE Error When Installing @agm/core with Angular 16.2.3

Tags: angular, google-maps, npm, dependency-management, agm-core

```bash
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: parkbilgi@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@16.2.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^16.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/common@"^9.1.0 || ^10.0.0" from @agm/core@3.0.0-beta.0
npm ERR! node_modules/@agm/core
npm ERR!   @agm/core@"*" from the root project
```

## Unable to Install @agm/core with Angular 16.2.3

### Problem

I'm working on an Angular project that requires Google Maps integration. I tried to install the `@agm/core` package, but I'm getting an `npm ERR! ERESOLVE` error.

My project uses Angular version 16.2.3, specified in `package.json` as:

```json
"@angular/common": "^16.1.0",
```

I want to install Angular Google Maps (AGM) in my Angular project

1. Is there a version of @agm/core that is compatible with Angular 16?
2. Are there alternative libraries or approaches to integrate Google Maps without downgrading Angular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This library is not supported anymore as you can see on [the repo](https://github.com/sebholstein/angular-google-maps/issues).

Per the peer deps it only supports v9/10. Also the support for non-ivy libs has been dropped in v16, so even if you forced install the deps, it wouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation on `@agm/core` and Angular 16 compatibility. I'll explore alternative approaches.

Comment: Did you find another approach? I am in the same boat having recently upgraded our project. NPM seems a little dry for anything other than AGM though. @FatihFurkanÇambel

Comment: I decided to stop using Angular Google Maps (AGM) in my Angular project because I couldn't find a solution for the new version of Angular. Currently, I am using OpenStreetMap and Leaflet. OpenStreetMap (OSM) is an open-source map database and mapping project. It has been a great choice for me as it fulfills all the requirements of my project. I highly recommend it to everyone. @Lewis Morgans

Comment: I used it in conjunction with Leaflet, but you can also use MapTiler. MapTiler is a JavaScript library used to visualize map and bookmark data. Similar to Leaflet, it is an open-source map library with features aimed at creating fast and interactive maps using WebGL technology.