# 'AgmCoreModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class

Tags: angular, angular17

'AgmCoreModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.(-996002)
core.module.d.ts(33, 56): This likely means that the library (@agm/core) which declares AgmCoreModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

The angular-google-maps core module. Contains all Directives/Services/Pipes of the core module. Please use AgmCoreModule.forRoot() in your app module.

AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
apiKey: '....'
})

Comment: Does this answer your question? [npm ERESOLVE Error When Installing @agm/core with Angular 16.2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77017543/npm-eresolve-error-when-installing-agm-core-with-angular-16-2-3)

Comment: Could you please provide a reproducible example of your issue on https://codesandbox.io/. This will allow the community to better understand the specific challenges you're facing and offer more targeted assistance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.